# Why is my sed {r FILE d} function not working?

Tags: macos, sed

I can't say that I understand the error message.

```
bash_prompt% sed -e '/__SUBSTITUTE_HERE__/ {r tmp.txt d}' < myFile.txt 
sed: 2: "/__SUBSTITUTE_HERE__/ { ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)
```

I'm using OSX 10.7.4 (Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0)

Goal is to substitute token in one file with contents of other file inside a bash script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -e '/__SUBSTITUTE_HERE__/ {r tmp.txt' -e 'd;}' < myFile.txt
```

see http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq5_008.html

Answer (score 2):

You should separate commands by `;` or newline in sed, not by a space. The `r` command seems to demand only the newline after the filename, though.

```
sed -e '/__SUBSTITUTE_HERE__/ {r tmp.txt
d}' < myFile.txt
```