# Load HTML with cat and import with sed through Makefile

Tags: sed, makefile, grep, cat

Long time lurker but first time poster. I have a Makefile question and wasn't sure where to post the question but so I hope I picked the right category.

I'm working with backbone templates and have split my html in multiple files.
The index files includes this `{template}` text. I'm planing to use tha Makefile to load the text from multiple HTML files and replace the `{template}` variable with the content from those files.

**Makefile**
include:

```
$(eval data := $(shell cat "file.html"))
sed -i '' 's/$({template})/$(data)/' index.html
```

The sed code works lika a charm and it replaces it with the data value if I force it to have text, but the cat breaks and gives me an `Error 1`.

I've tried both:

```
$(eval data := $(shell grep -nr file.html))
$(eval data := $(shell cat "file.html"))
```

They both fail when they reach some other than a regular character.
I've not yet figured out how to load the html data into the variable.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried `data := $(shell cat file.html)`? Some sample input (including non "regular characters") would be helpful in explaining the problem better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my sed {r FILE d} function not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799432/why-is-my-sed-r-file-d-function-not-working)

Comment: (Not really an exact duplicate, but I think the answer will work.)

Comment: This will not work at all, because every closing HTML tag will break with its slash the `s` command. Telling `sed` to read the file on its own as Beta suggested is the only way to go. But inventing a new template text format system is a bad move at all. [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) can do this much better with [SSI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/ssi.html) and [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) can do this much better with [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

Answer (score 0):

As the `/` character may be present in your `template` and your `data`, this would break your sed command.

There are two ways of handling this:

1. Use a different regex delimiter, that you are sure is not present in your strings.
2. Escape your `/` character.

The escaping can easily be done with this command:

```
sed -e 's:/:\\/:g'
```